# How to access a VM that is connected to a private network using another VM

Tags: networking, virtualization, vmware-workstation

I have 2 VMware virtual machines, each of them running Windows Server 2017 (Server Core) Build 17046. I'm using VMware.

VM #1 has access to the client - Network Adapter 1
VM #1 also has access to a private network (VMnet10) - Network Adapter 2

VM #2 ONLY has access to the private network (VMnet10) - Network Adapter 1
VM #2 is running the Minecraft server

What I'm trying to achieve is a way for the client to connect to VM #1's Port 25565, and VM #1 redirects the connection to VM #2's Port 25565

[diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqBsR.png)

In other words, I want the clients to be able to connect to VM #2 without any changes in the network configuration.

Here's a snip of how my network adapters look like in VMware:

[snip](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Io0Jq.png)

VM #1's first adapter is connected to Host-Only because, for now, my PC (the host) is the only client

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to setup port forwarding in your `VM #1` using the `netsh` tool.

For more details refer the following page:
[Netsh commands for Interface Portproxy | Microsoft Docs](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc731068(v=ws.10).aspx)

Also, don't forget to open port 25565 for incoming traffic in `VM #2's` firewall.